# ASP MVC can't display image in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sqlite

So I've got this image in the shape of a byte[] that I want to display in my view.

This is my model of the image:

```
    public class ImageModel
    {
        public Byte[] imageFirst { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my controller picking out the image from a db:

```
public ActionResult Image()
    {
        string cs = "Data Source=" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\ImageDB.db";

        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(cs))
        {
            var listOfImages = new List<ImageModel>();
            string stm = "SELECT * FROM Image";
            con.Open();

            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(stm, con))
            {
                using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        listOfImages.Add(new ImageModel
                        {
                            imageFirst = Serialize(rdr["image_first"]),
                        });
                    }

                    rdr.Close();
                    Images = listOfImages;
                }
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        return View(Images);
    }

    public static byte[] Serialize(object obj)
    {
        var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

And this is when I try to show the image in the view:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(@item.imageFirst))" width="300px"/>
```

But all I get is this icon: [image: View image fail]

I can't for the love of me figure out why it can't be shown. The images are stored as what I can only assume is a blob in the database, but right now I wish they were just image files on the disc, as that seems to make it a lot easier to attach them to the view.

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing.  You're adding the models to `listOfSlides` but returning the view with `listOfImages`, which appears to never be populated.

Comment: Yes that was indeed a little confusing! It's fixed now.

Comment: What is `rdr["image_first"]`? How are the images stored into this field?

Comment: It's an instance of the SQLiteDataReader reading from the database column "image_first" where the image is stored as a byte[].

Comment: Aren't you double encoding then? Is the serialize step necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `imageFirst` property is a valid image byte array, you may need to include html raw mode on the output:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,@Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(item.imageFirst))" width="300px"/>
```

Also, use `item` instead of `@item` since you are already inside of @(), or in the example `@Html.Raw`.

Answer (score -1):

Which browser you are using. IE has a size limit on the data URI, I think it is 32 KB. What is the size of your image string after converting to base64.